# Services: Getting error 406 Node type is required - but I have specified the node type

Tags: services

I'm trying to create a node using jQuery to POST JSON.

I get the following error returned by the server:
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 406 (Not Acceptable: Node type is required)

However, the type is definitely specified in my JSON string:

```
var data = '{"title":"Sample post ",
  "type":"article",
  "field_link":
            [{
             "url":"http://www.google.com", 
            "title":"My title"
            }],
  "body":
            {
             "und":[{"value":"comments about something"}]
             }
  }';
```

Comment: Use http://bit.ly/12wrHAF to debug

Answer (score 1):

1. try to observe the order of fields like: type > title > body > fields
2. that is the widget type of "field_link"?
3. add "und" to this field

   ```
   {"title":"Sample post ",
   "type":"article",
   "body":{
   "und":[{
   "value":"comments about something"}]},
   "field_link":{
   "und":[{
   "url":"http://www.google.com",
   "title":"My title"}]}}
   ```